# How to get all filenames inside a folder in assets folder in android?

Tags: android

How to get all filenames inside a folder in my assets folder in android?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Get an `AssetManager` (using `getAssets()` from a context or activity), and call `list("subdir")` from it(replacing **subdir** with the name of the folder inside your assets folder).

That will get you a `String[]` with all the filenames you seek.

Comment: That will give you the String[] with the name of the assets but, what about if you want to access to the file? as AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("elementOfSubdir"); and pass that file to a MediaPlayer for example.